# How can I reduce the redundance code such as with(drawScope) , drawIntoCanvas { }、 mCoordinate.run{ } in every function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A are from my Android Studio project.

I think it's not a good code , there are many redundance codes.

I have to write the same code such as `with(drawScope)`, `drawIntoCanvas { }`、 `mCoordinate.run{ }`    in every function.

I hop to improve it, how can it do? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Watch(
   ...
){
    Box(
       ...
    ) {
        Canvas(
          ...
        ) {    
              drawtDial(this)
              drawdivide(this)
              ...  
        }
    }
}

fun drawtDial(drawScope: DrawScope){
    with(drawScope) {
        drawIntoCanvas {           
            val mCoordinate = NewCoordinate(size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 2.0f)    
            mCoordinate.run{
                val radius = size.minDimension / 2 - 10
                it.drawCircle(Offset(x = 0.0f.toX, y = 0f.toY), radius, paintDial)
                it.drawArc(...)
                it.drawImage(...)
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}


fun drawdivide(drawScope: DrawScope){
    with(drawScope) {
        drawIntoCanvas {
            val mCoordinate = NewCoordinate(size.width / 4.0f, size.height / 4.0f)    
            mCoordinate.run{
                ...
                it.drawLine( Offset(x = x1.toX, y = y1.toY), Offset(x = x2.toX, y = y2.toY),pathBorderPaint)
                it.nativeCanvas.drawText(label, x2.toX, y2.toY, textPaint)
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}


class NewCoordinate(private val xOrigin: Float, private val yOrigin: Float) 
    val Float.toX: Float get() = xOrigin + this                   
    val Float.toY: Float get() = yOrigin - this                   
}
```

**Added Content:**

To Thracian: Thanks!

The Code B is written based your ideas, but it cause the error.

**Code B**

```
fun DrawScope.drawNormal(coordinate: NewCoordinate, block: (canvas: Canvas) -> Unit) {
    coordinate.run {
        drawIntoCanvas {
            block(it)
        }
    }
}

fun drawtDial(drawScope: DrawScope){
    val mCoordinate = NewCoordinate(drawScope.size.width / 2.0f, drawScope.size.height / 2.0f)
    drawScope.drawNormal(mCoordinate){
        it.drawLine(...)                          // It's Ok
        mCoordinate.run { var temp = 5.0f.toX }   // It's OK
        var temp = 5.0f.toX                       // It's Error! Why?
    }
}
```

**Added Content Again**

The Code D is answer based by cactustictacs's [thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500403/how-can-i-write-the-same-code-without-run-and-wth-in-kotlin). It works well.

**Code D**

```
fun drawDial(drawScope: DrawScope){   
    val mCoordinate = NewCoordinate(drawScope.size.width / 2.0f, drawScope.size.height / 2.0f)

    mCoordinate.draw(drawScope){
        it.drawCircle(Offset(x = 0.0f.toX, y = 0f.toY), Radius, paintDial)
    }
}

fun NewCoordinate.draw(drawScope: DrawScope, block: NewCoordinate.(canvas: Canvas) -> Unit ){
    drawScope.drawIntoCanvas{
        block(it)
    }
}


class NewCoordinate(private val xOrigin: Float, private val yOrigin: Float) {  
    val Float.toX: Float get() = xOrigin + this                  
    val Float.toY: Float get() = yOrigin - this                   
}
```

Comment: Coming up in either Kotlin 1.7 or 1.8 (I don’t remember which), they are going to start supporting function references with multiple receivers, which will make this much easier to resolve.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that there is not good way at present Kotlin version?

Comment: I'm not saying there's no good way, just that there will be a cleaner way to write a reusable function for this later. I don't use Compose, so can't write a good answer for your specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension function for DrawScope like this

```
fun DrawScope.drawDial(coordinate: Coordinate, block: Canvas.() -> Unit) {
    drawIntoCanvas { canvas: Canvas ->
        canvas.block()

    }
}
```

or like this

```
fun DrawScope.drawDial2(coordinate: Coordinate, block: (Canvas, Offset) -> Unit) {
    drawIntoCanvas { canvas: Canvas ->
        block(canvas, Offset(x = coordinate.x, coordinate.y))
    }
}
```

And use it as

```
val coordinate = Coordinate(1f, 2f)
Canvas(modifier = Modifier) {
    drawDial(coordinate) {
        drawCircle(Offset(x = coordinate.x, y = coordinate.y), 10f, Paint())
    }

    drawDial2(coordinate) { canvas: Canvas, offset: Offset ->
        canvas.drawCircle(offset, 10f, Paint())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope to write complex code in every separation function such as `fun drawtDial()`, `fun drawdivide()`, but your code maybe cause the  code `Canvas(modifier = Modifier) {..}` huge.

Comment: Code in canvas are 2 alternatives, no matter what you do you need to have `Canvas` or simply or a modifier that uses `DrawScope`.

Comment: Thanks! and more , your code hasn't handled the  `mCoordinate.run{}`

Comment: In my `fun drawtDial()`,  it need  to handle many drawing

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my modified content in the question?

Comment: In `drawDial2` i transform it into `Offset` so you can just use it with `canvas.drawCircle(offset, 10f, Paint())`

Comment: You can write you own transformations either, you just need to create an extension scope for `DrawScope` and fill inside it according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, could you write a full code for this question?

Comment: The paramater `block: (Canvas, Offset)` in `fun DrawScope.drawDial2` doesn't fit any case, you know maybe I should use the code such as  `it.nativeCanvas.drawText(label, x1.toX, y1.toY, textPaint)`.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?