# How can I write the same code without .run{...} and .wth{...} in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The Code B is a class, but I can't understand the Code B fully.

I can use the class `NewCoordinate` in Code A.

Can you write a the same function as Code A without using `.run{..}`  or  `.wth{..}` ?

**Code A**

```
fun doTo(){
    val mCoordinate = NewCoordinate(2.0f, 3.0f)
    mCoordinate.run { 
        var mPoint =3.0f.toX
    }
    
    with(mCoordinate){
        var mPoint =3.0f.toX
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class NewCoordinate(private val xOrigin: Float, private val yOrigin: Float) {  
    val Float.toX: Float get() = xOrigin + this                  
    val Float.toY: Float get() = yOrigin - this                   
}
```

**Added Content**

To cactustictacs: Thanks!

In Code C, I have added a extension function `.ext` for the class  `NewCoordinate`, it wrapped with `.run {...}`.

But I still get the wrong, why?

**Code C**

```
fun doTo() {
    val mCoordinate = NewCoordinate(2.0f, 3.0f)
    mCoordinate.ext {
        var mPoint =3.0f.toX  //It's wrong
    }
}

fun NewCoordinate.ext(block: ()->Unit){
    this.run {
        block()
    }
}


class NewCoordinate(private val xOrigin: Float, private val yOrigin: Float) {  
    val Float.toX: Float get() = xOrigin + this                  
    val Float.toY: Float get() = yOrigin - this                   
}
```

**Added Content Again**

The Code D is answer based by cactustictacs's thinking. It's great, thanks again.

**Code D**

```
fun drawDial(drawScope: DrawScope){   
    val mCoordinate = NewCoordinate(drawScope.size.width / 2.0f, drawScope.size.height / 2.0f)

    mCoordinate.draw(drawScope){
        it.drawCircle(Offset(x = 0.0f.toX, y = 0f.toY), Radius, paintDial)
    }
}

fun NewCoordinate.draw(drawScope: DrawScope, block: NewCoordinate.(canvas: Canvas) -> Unit ){
    drawScope.drawIntoCanvas{
        block(it)
    }
}


class NewCoordinate(private val xOrigin: Float, private val yOrigin: Float) {  
    val Float.toX: Float get() = xOrigin + this                  
    val Float.toY: Float get() = yOrigin - this                   
}
```

Comment: No you can't. The extensions of Float class can only be used inside a NewCoordinate reference scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
val Float.toX: Float get() = xOrigin + this
```

is an [extension property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-properties). It allows you to "add" a property to a class (in this case the `Float` class) without needing to modify the source of that class. So when that extension property is in scope (where the code you're running can "see" it) you can call `toX` on any `Float`, and it'll run that code.

If an extension is declared at the top level of the current file, anything in that file can access it - it's in scope. If it's at the top level of another file, and visibility modifiers allow it, you can `import` it - now it's in scope.

But if it's declared inside a class, only code *inside that class* (or its subclasses) can see it - it's not accessible from the outside. (If you look at the link up there, and scroll down to the *Declaring extensions as members* section, you can see an example where they explicitly demonstrate this)

---

So that's a problem - but what receiver-style scope functions like `run`, `apply` and `with` do is allow you to run code "inside" the object you're calling them on. It's as if your code is part of the object's class - and that means those `Float` extension properties are now in scope, and you can use them!

This doesn't allow you to get around visibility modifiers - if you make those properties `private` in `NewCoordinate`, you won't be able to access them. If you like, `run` is a bit like an extension function on `NewCoordinate` - you can "add" functionality that behaves as though it's part of the class's code, which makes use of stuff that's publicly accessible on the class.

It's shifting your point of reference, so you can access things more easily - but nothing that you couldn't access before! It's just that in this case, the language didn't allow you to reference `Float.toX` from outside the scope - the property is still public, but right now there's no way to say `mCoordinate::toX` or `mCoordinate::Float::toX` or anything like that. You have to put yourself in scope so you can call it the usual way!

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW your `block` parameter's type is `() -> Unit`, i.e. a general function with no parameters and no receiver, it can be run anywhere. It has no connection to the `NewCoordinate` type (you just happen to be running the function inside its scope) so it has no access to any of its member functions and properties through its current scope. If you want to make it a function that *does* run in that scope (and therefore has access to everything in it) `block`'s type needs to be `NewCoordinate.() -> Unit` - if you change that, it'll work!

Comment: OK, your  way is great.